# Error in boxM function after installing package and invoking library successfully

Tags: r

Code:

```
install.packages("biotools")
library(biotools)
boxM(train1[,2:6],train1[,1])
```

Error:

> Error in boxM(train1[, 2:6], train1[, 1]) :    could not find function
>   "boxM"

The package has been installed successfully as per console. Even after checking the checkbox for enabling the library, getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may try "heplots" package. It contains boxM function as well.